# Нужно ли двоеточие после слова "ним"

Tags: пунктуация

Люблю, умею, практикую, – вот такой вот простой девиз, и под ним P.S. Макс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После "ним" ничего не нужно, ведь P. S. - это постскриптум; читайте как "и под ним подпись - Макс".

А девиз желательно закавычить, и перед указательным местоимением (даже после прямой речи) запятая не ставится.

***"Люблю, умею, практикую!" – вот такой вот простой девиз, и под ним P. S.  –  Макс.***

Ничего не меняю в предложении, но впервые вижу так оформленный постскриптум, состоящий из одной подписи. Где же (и что же) "после сказанного"?!

Девиз без восклицательного знака тоже не часто встретишь (но не настаиваю)... Вспомнилось только "Veni, vidi, vici".

Если это Ваш собственный текст (а не предложенный для расстановки знаков), я бы сделала так:

***"Люблю, умею, практикую" – вот такой вот простой девиз.***
***И под ним подпись – Макс.***

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Да, это мой текст.

Comment: Ой, я только что заметила два "вот", но эта избыточность имеет право быть авторской. И (информация для новичков на сайте) если ответ оказался полезным, помог, следует кликнуть по стрелочке вверх, а клик по звёздочке будет означать, что ответ Вы получили исчерпывающий, в дополнительной информации не нуждаетесь.